# Can we use unions instead of structs if we're just reading the members?

Tags: c, memory, struct, unions

So, my question is, can't memory be saved by using unions instead of structs when you aren't changing the members? I know that other members will also be affected by change operations, but what I don't change anything, what if I just want to read them? For example:

```
struct my_struct{
   int age;
   int salary;
   int id;
};
```

Can't we save 8 bytes there by simply replacing struct with union(if I don't change anything)?

```
union my_union{
   int age;
   int salary;
   int id;
};
```

sizeof(my_union) is 4, and sizeof(my_struct) is 12. This is just an example, but can't we do this if we don't need to actually change anything?

Comment: If you want your `age` to be equal to `salary` and `id` - then go on... Do you understand what `union` is and how it is different from `struct`?

Comment: A union only has 1 member at a time. No matter if you change anything or not.

Comment: @EugeneSh. When you change a member, other members also get changed

Comment: @dfmaaa1 But why are they changed? Because all the members are sharing the *same* memory address. That is if you have three `int's at the same place in memory, they are effectively the same `int`. So you will read the exact same value from all of them.

Comment: @EugeneSh. :( so they have to be different types?

Comment: No. They will still share the same memory, and in case of different types things will get nastier, as `int` are at least compatible with each other, but different types will interpret the *same bytes* in memory as different value. Please take some time reading about the concept of `union` in you favorite C book or online resource.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `my_union` is only 4 bytes is because it's only storing one `int` worth of data. i.e. `my_union.age` is stored in the same memory location as `my_union.salary` and `my_union.id`.

So, think of it like this: "Can't we save 8 bytes by replacing `my_struct` with a single `int`?" If the answer is no, think about why. Because this is basically what you're doing if you try to replace it with `my_union`.

To help visualize this, let's look at how the memory is laid out for `my_struct` vs `my_union:

`my_struct`:

```
| age     | salary  | id      |
| 4 bytes | 4 bytes | 4 bytes |
```

i.e., we have 12 bytes, divided into three sections of 4 bytes each, one for each member.

`my_union`:

```
| age     |
| salary  | 
| id      |
| 4 bytes |
```

i.e. we have only have 4 bytes. We still have 3 members, but they're all stored in the same spot. It's like we just have a single `int`.